# STRAPI : how to get data from admin controller in admin ui

Tags: strapi

System

Node.js version: 12.9.1
NPM version: 6.10.2
Strapi version: 3.0.0-beta.15
Database: MySQL
Operating system: ubuntu 10

Topic
get data from controller to admin ui

path : admin/src/components/leftMenuLinkContainer/index.js

```
import { all,call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { request } from 'strapi-helper-plugin';
console.log("here you are in leftmenu container index.js");
const { currentEnv } = call(request, `/admin/currentEnvironment`, { method: 'GET' });
console.log(currentEnv); 
const {currentEnvironment} = all(
  call(request, `/admin/currentEnvironment`, { method: 'GET' })
);
console.log(currentEnvironment);
```

i've tried "NODE_ENV", "process.env", "NODE_ENV" etc. when i'm trying "NODE_ENV" it returns production in development and production mode both. any way to get config in admin ui, i can get environment name in controller using "proces.env" but i don't know how to send data from controller to admin ui

Comment: Hello, I start my application using `yarn develop` in the admin panel, I opened the browser network, check the result of the `/admin/currentEnvironment` request and see `currentEnvironment ` as `development`. and if I start my app with `NODE_ENV=production`, I refresh the browser and I see the `currentEnvironment ` as `production`. So this route send you the correct value.

Comment: I don't really understand your need here.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here for those searching for a way to do this in Strapi v4.

Shamelessly stolen from https://github.com/offset-dev/strapi-calendar/blob/master/admin/src/utils/axiosInstance.js

```
import { auth } from '@strapi/helper-plugin';

export const adminFetch = async (url: string, options: RequestInit = {}) => {
    return fetch(url, {
        ...options,
        headers: {
            ...options.headers,
            Authorization: ((options?.headers as Record<string, string>)?.['Authorization'] as string) || `Bearer ${auth.getToken()}`,
            Accept: ((options?.headers as Record<string, string>)?.['Accept'] as string) || 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': ((options?.headers as Record<string, string>)?.['Content-Type'] as string) || 'application/json',
        },
    });
};
```

This can then be used like regular fetch:

```
adminFetch(`${process.env.STRAPI_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL}/your-plugin/your-route`)
```